# what is main(ac, av) int ac; char **av; {...}?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many styles of writing functions are there in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655042/how-many-styles-of-writing-functions-are-there-in-c)

I saw a program written in C with the following definition of `main`:

```
main(ac, av) int ac; char **av;
{
    ...
}
```

instead of

```
int main(int argc, char **argc)
{
    ...
}
```

I've never seen a C syntax as in the first code. What is it and where can I read about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one is an old-style, pre-ANSI, C function header before function prototypes became the common/standard way of writing code.

Frequently formatted like this:

```
main(ac, av) 
int ac; 
char **av;
{
    ...
}
```

What you see after the initial set of parenthesis are the type declarations for the parameters in `main`. Also note, no `int` return type is declared.

No one really writes code like that, stick to the 2nd form.

If you can dig up the [original white book by Kernighan and Ritchie](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131101633) (1st ed, pre-ANSI) you'll see that form (and as @dirkgently correctly mentions this is sometimes referred to as K&R style C) as you would in other older C books.

Also check out this link if you are curious 
[Obsolete Forms of Function Declarations and Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efx873ys.aspx). Searching on "old style C function declarations" in google will bring up a number of hits.

Comment: This is also called [K&R C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#K.26R_C).